# Define width of div in HTML (set max-width)

Tags: css

This should be so easy, but I just cannot get it to work.

I have a div that will contain a kind of tooltip on a Google map (an implementation of google.maps.OverlayView). The amount of text to be displayed is variable. It could be a single (short) word or several sentences. The width of the div should be at most, say, 150px. If the whole text needs less than 150px to display (on a single line), the div should be only as small (ie as wide) as needed. Longer text should be broken into several lines, the div being at most 150px wide.

I thought all that needed to be done (in the css) would be to set "max-width: 150px;". But this does not do what I want (I am testing in IE8): The text gets line-broken **at every white space** (!!) and the div ends up smaller than 150px wide. (When I set "width: 150px;" the div gets wider than I want when the text is short.)

Why does the text (when longer) not fill the max-width, but get broken up far too often? ("Playing around" with word-wrap or text-wrap did not help.)

Is it possible to say: Keep the div as narrow as possible if text fits on one line, and otherwise, don't make it wider than 150px?

Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

Thanks for the answers / comments, but my problem remains.

My CSS, unspectacularyl, looks like this:

```
.TTWayPoint {
    max-width:      150px;
    border:         1px solid black;
    padding:        3px;
    background-color:   lightyellow;
    font:           8pt Verdana, Tahoma, "Microsoft Sans Serif", sans-serif;
}
```

The problem is that longer text gets broken (line wrapped) at every whitespace, i.e. does not fill the max-width. Playing with the display property has not helped.

It seems to me that this is an IE8 issue. (I am actually developping a VB.NET application having a Webbrowser control; AFAIK that means that you are using the version of IE installed on your system, which in my case is IE8 (can't be updated on XP).)

Comment: I was kinda surprised myself for a second (posted a wrong answer first), but your use case works fine, as demonstrated in [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/MXcuh/). Your code must have other issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by setting the div to `display: table` or `display: inline-block;`. Here's an example with `display: table`:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nlhLp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">

div {background: #e7e7e7; display: table; max-width: 130px; padding: 10px; margin: 0 auto 40px;}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div>Some text</div>

<div>Some text some text some text some text</div>

</body>
</html>
```